# Three20 "pull down to update" isn't showing last update time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

When I implement this method in my TTTableViewController:

```
- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
    return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

I get the "pull down to update..." feature, *however*, it's not displaying the date and time of the last update (like I see on the facebook and twitter apps).

I'm sure this is because I'm not implementing some protocol method or something like that, but I'm not sure exactly which method(s) I need to implement. The table is displaying my data just fine, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any ideas?

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

But this is what I want to see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your model inheriting from TTURLRequestModel? If so, as the last thing in your

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request
```

call

```
[super requestDidFinishLoad:request];
```

Updating the timestamp is what happens in there. If your model is not inheriting from TTURLRequestModel you can still check the source code of that one to see what's involved.